# What is the maximizer of the Hardy-Littlewood-Sobolev fractional integration inequality

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Let $ 0 < \alpha < n $, and define
$$I_\alpha f (x): = \int_{ \mathbb R^n } \frac{f (y) }{  |x - y| ^\alpha }\, d y. $$

The Hardy-Littlewood-Sobolev fractional integration inequality states:

If $1 < p< q < \infty$ and  $ \frac{1}{p}-\frac{1}{q} =  1-\frac{ \alpha }{ n} $ then

$$\| I_ \alpha f \|_{ L^q ( \mathbb R ^n )} \le C_{p ,\alpha , n }\||f\|_{ L^ p(\mathbb R^n )}. \qquad(1)$$

Are there known maximizers (possibly up to a constant) of (1).
A reference or idea of proof would be very helpful.

A maximizer of (1) is a function $f$ for which (1) is an equality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice first that by duality, your inequality is equivalent to the Hardy-Littlewood-Sobolev inequality
$$
\iint \frac{f(x)\,g(y)}{|x-y|^\alpha}\,\mathrm d x\,\mathrm d y ≤ C_{p,\alpha,n}\, \|f\|_{L^p}\,\|g\|_{L^{q'}}.
$$
where $q' = \tfrac{q}{q-1}$.

The maximizers and the optimal constant are only explictly known in the case $p=q'$. In this case $p=\frac{2\,n}{2\,n-\alpha}$ and as proved by Lieb
$$
C_{p,\alpha,n} = \pi^{\alpha/2} \,\frac{\Gamma(\tfrac{n}{2}-\tfrac{\alpha}{2})}{\Gamma(n-\tfrac{\alpha}{2})} \left(\frac{\Gamma(n)}{\Gamma(\tfrac{n}{2})}\right)^{1-\alpha/n}
$$
and the optimizers are the functions of the form
$$
f(x) = \frac{C}{(a^2+|x-b|^2)^{(2n-\alpha)/2}}
$$
See e.g. Theorem 4.3 in the book *Analysis* by Lieb and Loss (and the remarks after).

In the other cases, the optimizers are known to exist, but I think they are not known explicitly, and the optimal constant is not known. However, there are bounds from above for the constant, and the minizers might be linked to the fast diffusion/porous media equation (see e.g. Hardy-Littlewood-Sobolev inequalities via fast diffusion flows)

Comment: How are upper bounds on the constants proved ? I expect using sequences of functions $f_n$ for which $\|I_{\alpha}f _n\|_{q}/\|f_n\|_{p}$ converges to the upper bound on the constant. If true, then what does $f_{n}$ look like ?

Comment: No, these are just upper bounds coming from the proof of the inequality.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the theorem @LL 3.14 is referring to in his answer from "Analysis" by Lieb and Loss:

[image]